# Copy files from drive mounted on Jenkins controller to Jenkins agent machine

Tags: windows, jenkins, share, drive, jenkins-agent

### The environment

- Controller has access to shared drive `X:\`
- Controller has Jenkins as a Windows service
- Agent is on a Windows machine in same network as the controller
- Agent most likely will not have access to drive `X:\` (there will be many agents PCs running this in the future)

### The scenario

***I need to copy some files from drive `X:\` to the agent machine**, but this is a conditional step based on a parameter of the job, so this should be a pipeline step as we don't want to copy the files if not needed. The files to copy might be large so stash/unstash is not an option.*

So basically my question is, Is there a simple way to solve the scenario without having to give access to `X:\` drive to the agent(s)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you think you should copy the files to a neutral location, like a binary repo and copy from there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm looking into this option now but I haven't yet made a decision

Answer (score 0):

So ultimately I found that stash has no hard limit, for now I'm using stash/unstash even on large files and there is no error (e.g. 1.5 Gb) until we start using a different method, like the one in Holleoman's answer